# I am using NavigationContainer in React Native and now the page is completely blank

Tags: react-native, supabase, stack-navigator

I am using NavigationContainer in React Native and now the page is completely blank

```js
import React from 'react';
import AuthScreen from './Authentication/AuthScreen';
import { StripeProvider } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';
import { STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY } from './env';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
// import supabase from './Authentication/supabaseConfig';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StripeProvider publishableKey={STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="AuthScreen">
          <Stack.Screen name="AuthScreen" component={AuthScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="HomeScreen"
            component={HomeScreen}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </StripeProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I tried reviewing my imports across the component files, and checking that i had all my dependancies installed.